# How to push an element from an ng-repeat into another

Tags: angularjs

The problem is that I don't know and I didn't found how to do what's written in the title. How do I grab the element whose link is being clicked, and then push its value into an array?

[Demo at Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z976RUNcqlXsbdDd2EeG?p=preview)

from app.js

```
  $scope.orderList = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.orderList.push($scope.pizza.name);
  };
```

from view.html

```
<div ng-controller="orderCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-focus="example()" ng-blur="default()" />
    <ul ng-hide="pizzaSvg">
      <li ng-repeat="pizza in pizze | filter:search | orderBy: 'name'" ng-model="orderList"><a href="" ng-click="add()">{{pizza.name}}</a><br/>{{pizza.ingredients}}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-show="pizzaSvg">
      <li ng-repeat="order in orderList"><a href="">[x]</a> {{order}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass your pizza as a parameter to the add function:

```
  $scope.orderList = [];
  $scope.add = function(pizza) {
    $scope.orderList.push(pizza.name);
  };
```

Then in your html:

```
<div ng-controller="orderCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-focus="example()" ng-blur="default()" />
    <ul ng-hide="pizzaSvg">
      <li ng-repeat="pizza in pizze | filter:search | orderBy: 'name'" ><button ng-click="add(pizza)">{{pizza.name}}</button><br/>{{pizza.ingredients}}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-show="pizzaSvg">
      <li ng-repeat="order in orderList"><button>[x]</button> {{order}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also, avoid using `<a>` for clickable elements, usually something like `<button>` will work more cleanly as the browser won't try to follow a link as its default `click` action.

Comment: Uhm orderList is keeping itself empty :-/

Comment: @EmanueleTuttolani, perhaps the `ng-show="pizzaSvg"` is preventing the orderList displaying?

Comment: No because I even put `{{orderList}}` outside of the ul, it just isn't being pushed

Comment: Your first ng-repeat had a spurious `ng-model="orderList"` that was probably overwriting the value you pushed.

Comment: If it can help anyhow, this works:
 `$scope.remove = function(pizza) {
  var index;
  index = $scope.orderList.indexOf(pizza);
  $scope.orderList.splice(index, 1);
};`

`button(ng-click="remove()") Rimuovi` this is in .jade

Comment: Found the problem.. it's related to the ng-focus and ng-blur (or maybe ng-show and ng-hide as you suggested): what's in the ng-click of the button triggers on the release of it, so actually the code works but I don't trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically do this with a button like so:

```
<ul ng-show="pizzaSvg">
  <li ng-repeat="order in orderList"><button ng-click="add(order)">[x]</a> {{order}}</li>
</ul>
```

The reasoning is because a link in my view is meant for moving from page to page, where as a button will be used to execute an action.